# Real time dynamic emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, content

A client of mine is making the switch from Selligent to Salesforce Marketing Cloud and wants to show the most recent opening hours in their e-mail. Real-time stock is also a nice to have. Is there a way how this content can be real-time based on open time?

I've seen examples such as Pixlee, Movable Ink & Liveclicker (can't find this one on AppExchange) but no concrete examples.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at e.g. Movable Ink and other vendors is a good start, as the only supported feature in Marketing Cloud is [Live Image](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_live_image.htm&type=5), which can only replace an image based on a specific rule (e.g. show image X before 20th of October and show image Y afterwards)

Mind you, whatever solution you opt for, it can only be based on images as text content cannot be altered once the email is sent. This can be an issue when images are cached by e.g. Gmail, and will not update each time the email is opened to e.g. reflect the updated stock status. Let's say you send an email on Monday, and client opens it on Wednesday. They will see stock status from Wednesday (so far so good). But if it is opened again on Thursday, the stock status from Wednesday might still persist.

If you are interested in showing product recommendations with updated stock information (i.e. hiding products out of stock), updated pricing, etc. you could also look into [Einstein Email Recommendations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_email_recommendations.htm&type=5)

Comment: Ok, that is clear. Thanks! Can the Live Image also be used for stock? Or real time opening hour calls? Or is it predefined what will be shown? Would you say that Moveable Ink can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Live Image will not be able to do so, as you need a solution which renders images dynamically based on data from you ecommerce system. Live Image uses predefined images. I have added another option for product recommendations native to SFMC

Comment: We are setting up Personalization Builder then for that, what about the opening hours?

Comment: I don't think they change that often, that it is a real issue? I am yet to find a client where updating it when doing the next email send has been an issue. At least not a use case justifying the cost of e.g. Movable Ink license

Comment: No they don't really change that often so you've got a valid point. Does Einstein Email Recommendations automatically show the real-time stock of a specific product in the email or do we need to do something special for that?

Comment: You will not see real time stock (as per my answer above) but products out of stock will not be recommended. Please remember upvoting and accepting this, and my previous answer to you, if you find them helpful