# Continuous Pull in Ampscript, GTL, or SSJS from a JSON file

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, ssjs, gtl

I am trying to find the best method in a Marketing Cloud email to continuously pull data from a JSON file that updates every 5 seconds so that it is "Live" Data within the email.

Currently I am using Ampscript and SSJS to pull in the data upon send to the individual recipient. This also allows the VAWP link to show the current data upon refresh for a limited time.

EDIT: We would like it to continuously update and show after the email send, similar to a countdown timer, but it is counting up based on the data in the JSON.

**JSON Data Example**

```
{
   "Odometers": [
       {
          "LevelId": 28,
          "Value": 57102.82
       },
       {
          "LevelId": 914,
          "Value": 50863.31
       }
   ]
}
```

**Code Snippet Example**

```
%%[
var @response,@value,@progressive,@locale

set @response = HTTPGET("https://URL/filename.json",false,0,@CallStatus)
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
//Get the @response variable from AMPscript
var json = Variable.GetValue("@response");

//Extract the nested JSON objects
var _JsonObject = eval('(' + json + ')');
  
//Set the @value variable to be accessible in AMPscript. If there are multiple data rows, start the row count at 0 for the first row to get a match level ID.
Variable.SetValue("@value",_JsonObject.Odometers[0].Value);

//Updates upon send, and also when VAWP link is clicked, or on refresh of the VAWP link.
</script>

%%[
set @locale = "en-US"
set @progressive  = FormatCurrency(@value, @locale)
]%%

The current amount is %%=v(@progressive)=%%
<br><br>
 @response: %%=v(@response)=%%
```

Comment: Do you want it to update the email content based on the JSON, even after the email is sent?

Comment: Yes. That is a good clarification. I will make an edit to my question. We would like it to continuously update and show after the email send, similar to a countdown timer, but it is counting up based on the data in the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not technically possible to replace/update text content in an email after it has been sent. The examples shown e.g. here: [How to refer Javascript cloud page in my email in content builder?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/322161/how-to-refer-javascript-cloud-page-in-my-email-in-content-builder/322170#322170) and or here: [Real time dynamic emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279649/real-time-dynamic-emails/279650#279650) all rely on images, that are fetched at open. But the referencing URLs remain the same once the email has been generated and sent.

All of the technologies you mention: SSJS, GTL, Ampscript are processed at sendtime, and content from any external URLs will not be refreshed afterwards.